Incorrect French characters php - website
I inherited a website to rebuild, which is displaying French characters incorrectly (â€™ for ‘, Ã© for é, Ã¨ for è and so on). These characters are also present as such in the mysql database. The database collation and the collation of content tables was set to “latin_swedish1_ci” when I received it. The websites html header contains <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />.
In order to correct the data I have updated the database collation and the one from one table (as a test) to “utf8mb4_unicode_ci” through phpmyadmin > operations which (as far as I understood) applies an ALTER function. However after these actions, the strings in the database and the table still contain the incorrect characters. Also when exported with utf-8 encoding, the content in the table is showing the incorrect characters.

Does this mean I would need to clean up all the records in the database, or do I overlook something and is there still a way to get the correct characters through the charsets and collation settings?

Changing collation doesn't modify table contents. See How to convert an entire MySQL database characterset and collation to UTF-8?

FWIW, although not ideal, latin_swedish1_ci can store French characters just fine, and MySQL can handle UTF-8 input/output correctly (as long as you don't have Unicode characters not available in Latin1). A possible common issue here is failing to declare what encoding your application uses when you establish database connection.

Also, <meta> tag is pretty much irrelevant in most cases, and it doesn't change document or data encoding.

See "Mojibake" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored

@RickJames This pointed me to double encoding and the hex query confirmed this as the problem, thank you! MySQL Charset/Collate is pretty scary, but I did find the solution in there and was able to correct the entries. So... another thank you for that page!
